# Querying specific Google Sheets worksheet via URL, SQL-style

Tags: google-sheets

The Google sheet at the URL below contains two worksheets, Sheet1, Sheet2.

Google sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pgdF1hoid8m1Zj3KburwjZRGkydLh1Sum4DshUMaIeo/edit#gid=0

When I use the Query URL #1 below, it successfully returns a JSON file with the correct result for the query:
SELECT B where A contains "nut"
(the result being the string "crunch")

Query URL #1:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pgdF1hoid8m1Zj3KburwjZRGkydLh1Sum4DshUMaIeo/gviz/tq?tq=SELECT%20B%20where%20A%20contains%20%22nut%22

Please note that the worksheet "sheet2" contains a different table as you can see at:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pgdF1hoid8m1Zj3KburwjZRGkydLh1Sum4DshUMaIeo/edit#gid=1652705509

If I try to query that worksheet with the Query URL #2 shown below, it does not work (it should return a json file with the result "raccoon"). Instead of returning that json file, it only displays that worksheet. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Query url #2:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pgdF1hoid8m1Zj3KburwjZRGkydLh1Sum4DshUMaIeo/edit#gid=1652705509/gviz/tq?tq=SELECT%20B%20where%20A%20contains%20%22bird%22

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is `/edit#gid=1652705509/` in the query string.

To target Sheet2, do this:

`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pgdF1hoid8m1Zj3KburwjZRGkydLh1Sum4DshUMaIeo/gviz/tq?tq=SELECT%20B%20where%20A%20contains%20%22bird%22&sheet=Sheet2`

Note the end parameter `&sheet=Sheet2`.

Comment: This works great. You made my day. Thank you.

Comment: I "accepted" your answer (didn't know I could do that-thx for letting me know). Don't yet have the voting privilege to vote it up. Thanks again!!